# deserialize Json to Java with Polymorphic members

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, genson

I'm trying to deserialize a json string to java object with genson but could not succeed. My class structure is like this:

```
public class Condition {
}

public class SimpleCondition extends Condition {
    String feature;
    String op;
    String value;
    int primitive;
}

public class ComplexCondition extends Condition {
    private Condition left;
    private String joint;
    private Condition right;
}
```

As you can see `ComplexCondition` may have another `ComplexCondition` or a `SimpleCondition` as its member for both `left` and `right`. The json that I get is like this:

```
{
  "left": {
            "feature":"locality",
            "op":"==",
            "value":"Chino"
            "primitive":9,
          },
  "joint":"and",
  "right": {
              "feature":"ch4",
              "op":">=",
              "value":"1.5",
              "primitive":3
           }
}
```

In this json, a `ComplexCondition` has both `left` and `right` as `SimpleCondition`s. But a general json string that I receive could be anything ranging from a `SimpleCondition` to any level of nesting for `ComplexCondition`s. I tried setting `@class` values in the json string but still genson could not deserialize it. I appreciate any help in deserializing this json to java using any library.

Comment: I doubt that provided json can be deserialized into provided java objects by any generic library, as there are no data about java class names for library to use. Probably you will have to write your own deserialization

Comment: Thanks for your time @Lashane. I did the deserialization myself by having constructors in both `SimpleCondition` and `ComplexCondition` that accept a JSON object and based on the object properties in it I'm making recursive calls in `ComplexCondition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register some aliases for your classes and then refer to them in your json like this:

```
Genson genson = new GensonBuilder()
    .addAlias("ComplexCondition", ComplexCondition.class)
    .addAlias("SimpleCondition", SimpleCondition.class)
    .create();

{
  "@class": "ComplexCondition",
  "left": {
            "@class": "SimpleCondition",
            "feature":"locality",
            "op":"==",
            "value":"Chino",
            "primitive":9
          },
  "joint":"and",
  "right": {
            "@class": "SimpleCondition",
              "feature":"ch4",
              "op":">=",
              "value":"1.5",
              "primitive":3
           }
}
```

You also need to add get and set methods for your ComplexCondition or make its field public or provide a constructor which takes them as arguments or configure genson to use private fields.

And last note, the class metadata attribute must be defined before attributes that are not prefixed by @. If you generate this json with Genson, it will always respect this constraint.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question but it did not work. It initializes the `Condition` class but does not set anything on it. So if I try to cast it to either `Simple` or `Complex` I get a `ClassCastException`. Could you please check that once?

Comment: Probably because the attributes from ComplexCondition are all private and you don't have any getter/setter. I just tried by generating get and set methods for them and all works perfectly fine. BTW there is a typo in the json, which makes it invalid. I updated the answer with the corrected json

Comment: I do have all the getters and setters, I just ignored them in the question. In fact I've `toString()` methods in both `Simple` and `Complex` condition classes. The result that I see for your json is `(columbus.service.model.Condition@7fbe847c and columbus.service.model.Condition@41975e01)` where as what I'm expecting is this - `((locality == Chino) and (ch4 >= 1.5))`.

Comment: Even if I set `useRuntimeType(true)` on the `GensonBuilder()` I see the default string representation that basically means the object is of type `Condition` and not one of the subtypes.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but with last version of Genson the code above works just fine. I have updated my answer with a fully runnable code try it out...

Comment: Alright, I think I found a bug in the library. It is expecting the `@class` as the first member of the JSON object, otherwise it fails to deserialize it. Could you please check that once and confirm? And how do I make sure that `@class` appears as the first element in the JSON string?

Comment: From [genson user guide](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/#polymorphic-types) Metadata must always be the first name/value pairs in json objects - meaning `@class` should appear as the first member. I'll see how I can get the ordered json. Please update your answer mentioning this, I'll accept it.

Comment: ok updated. It is not a bug but a limitation that allows Genson to be fast even when deserializing objects with class metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. If anyone can give a better solution, I would be happy to accept it.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Condition {
    public static Condition getCondition(JSONObject json){
        if(json.has("left"))
            return new ComplexCondition(json);
        else if(json.has("feature"))
            return new SimpleCondition(json);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid json for a Condition");
    }
}

public class ComplexCondition extends Condition{
    private Condition left;
    private String joint;
    private Condition right;

    public ComplexCondition(JSONObject json){
        if(json.has("left")){
            JSONObject leftJSON = json.getJSONObject("left");
            if(leftJSON.has("left"))
                this.left = new ComplexCondition(leftJSON);
            else
                this.left = new SimpleCondition(leftJSON);

            this.joint = json.getString("joint");

            JSONObject rightJSON = json.getJSONObject("right");
            if(rightJSON.has("left"))
                this.right = new ComplexCondition(rightJSON);
            else
                this.right = new SimpleCondition(rightJSON);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid json for a complex condition");
        }
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class SimpleCondition extends Condition{
    private String feature;
    private String op;
    private String value;
    private int primitive;

    public SimpleCondition(JSONObject json) {
        if(json.has("feature")){
            this.feature = json.getString("feature");
            this.op = json.getString("op");
            this.value = json.getString("value");
            this.primitive = json.getInt("primitive");
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid json for a simple condition");

    }

    //getters and setters
}
```